Merging certain font variants from several TTF files into a single TTF file
I want to use Libre Baskerville (a Google Font) on my Wordpress website, by uploading it rather than embedding the Google Fonts code. Why I want to do that is perhaps beyond the scope of this question (belongs on another site).
But I'm pretty sure I can do it by creating one TTF file with just the font variants I want: 800 weight for Bold, 400 and 800 weight for Italic and Italic Bold, and 400 weight for Regular. So that is my question.
Libre Baskerville is provided by Google in three separate TTF files. Can I use Font Forge or a similar free app to merge the three TTF files, selecting just the 800 and 400 weights?
